# Unusual TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json

**Yes, this has been asked before probably but I cannot find my problem only other variations of it.**

I am sending a get request to get warranty details about my products, when I try to parse the json this is what I'm getting.

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

This is the json entry
`[{'Id': 'LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-X-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-X1-CARBON-TYPE-20FB-20FC/20FB/20FBCTO1WW/my_serial', 'Guid': '', 'Brand': 'TPG', 'Name': 'X1 Carbon 4th Gen (Type 20FB, 20FC) Laptop (ThinkPad) - Type 20FB', 'Serial': '------', 'Type': 'Product.Serial', 'ParentID': ['9FD94C57-4A34-44BB-79C6-437A4468F0BC', 'A3D3B76A-9BDC-47FC-90C9-45266B9EFE49', '63986A45-3DF9-495B-83F5-C481E747FDBE', 'AC099204-FBB5-408D-83F1-B7A799CA7FDE', '4F17B2FC-75C9-454A-836E-BE95E4F89B1A'], 'Image': 'https://download.lenovo.com/images/ProdImageLaptops/x1carbon_g4.jpg', 'Popularity': '', 'IsSupported': True}]`

My code:

```
r = requests.get(url + "my_products_serial_number")
data = r.json()
print(data['Id'])
```

Expected output: `LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-X-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-X1-CARBON-TYPE-20FB-20FC`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the structure you posted: `data` is a *list*, not a *dict*:

```
[{'Id':
    ...
 }]
```

A list cannot be indexed by a string.  What I expect you want is

```
data[0]['Id']
```

`data` is a list; `data[0]` is a dict.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON results is a list that each item is a dict/json object so you can get the 'id' by of the first item by.

```
print(data[0]['Id'])
```